# Поменять количество выводимых знаков после запятой cout

Tags: c++

На вход поступает 3 числа m, n и k. Нужно разделить m на n, а после округлить до k знаков после запятой, проблема заключается в том что когда делишь например 10/3, то выводится только 5 знаком после запятой 3.33333. Как изменить количество выводимых знаков после запятой?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    float m, n, k;
    cin >> m >> n >> k;
    cout << round((m/n) * pow(10, k))/pow(10, k) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Учтите, что в типе `float` мантисса 24 bit, в которых может поместиться только 6 (ну, иногда 7) десятичных цифр. Остальным верить все равно нельзя. Если нужна большая точность, то используйте `double`. Для форматирования вывода через `cout` используйте [precision/setprecision](https://cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios_base/precision/) (хотя, на мой вкус, форматы [fprintf](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fprintf.3p.html) на практике значительно удобней)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуй использовать следующий код как пример:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    double e = exp(1);
    cout << fixed << setprecision(8) << e << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Думаю, что setprecision(N), где N - тот параметр, который тебя интересует